# How to do PDF Comparison in Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried PDF Comparison using PDFBOX jar files but it is not working for few PDFs so Can anyone tell us the other ways to do PDF comparison in selenium using Java

Comment: You can try check file sizes.

Comment: (Depending on the documents to compare and the results required, this may be anywhere between trivial and intractable: please edit your question to include not only *how* `it is not working for few PDFs` (and for which), but a description of documents to compare and the results required, too.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this link which having nice utils for comparison pdf file [pdf comparison](https://github.com/as842718/pdf-util)

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but from the description this looks like practical convenience classes based on PDFBox.